# Why does Python's dis dislike lists?

Tags: python, python-2.x

In Python (2.7.2),why does

```
import dis
dis.dis("i in (2, 3)")
```

works as expected whereas

```
import dis
dis.dis("i in [2, 3]")
```

raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dis.py", line 45, in dis
  disassemble_string(x)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dis.py", line 112, in disassemble_string
  labels = findlabels(code)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dis.py", line 166, in findlabels
 oparg = ord(code[i]) + ord(code[i+1])*256
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Note that this doesn't affect Python3.

Comment: But `dis.dis("a = [2, 3]; i in a")` works fine

Comment: it works in python 3.2.3

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Short Answer

In Python 2.x, the `str` type holds raw bytes, so `dis` assumes that if you pass it a string it is getting compiled bytecode. It tries to disassemble the string you pass it as bytecode and -- purely due to the implementation details of Python bytecode -- succeeds for `i in (2,3)`. Obviously, though, it returns gibberish.

In Python 3.x, the `str` type is for *strings* and the `bytes` types is for raw bytes, so `dis` can distinguish between compiled bytecode and strings -- and assumes it is getting source code if it gets a string.

---

### Long Answer

Here's the thought process I followed to work this one out.

1. I tried it on my Python (3.2):

   ```
   >>> import dis
   >>> dis.dis("i in (2,3)")  
     1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (i)
                 3 LOAD_CONST               2 ((2, 3))
                 6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
                 9 RETURN_VALUE
   >>> dis.dis("i in [2,3]")
     1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (i)
                 3 LOAD_CONST               2 ((2, 3))
                 6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
                 9 RETURN_VALUE
   ```

   Obviously, this works.
2. I tried it on Python 2.7:

   ```
   >>> import dis
   >>> dis.dis("i in (2,3)")
             0 BUILD_MAP       26912
             3 JUMP_FORWARD    10272 (to 10278)
             6 DELETE_SLICE+0
             7 <44>
             8 DELETE_SLICE+1
             9 STORE_SLICE+1
   >>> dis.dis("i in [2,3]")
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "C:\Python27\lib\dis.py", line 45, in dis
       disassemble_string(x)
     File "C:\Python27\lib\dis.py", line 112, in disassemble_string
       labels = findlabels(code)
     File "C:\Python27\lib\dis.py", line 166, in findlabels
       oparg = ord(code[i]) + ord(code[i+1])*256
   IndexError: string index out of range
   ```

   Aha! Notice also that the generated bytecode in Python 3.2 is what you would expect ("load `i`, load `(2,3)`, test for membership, return the result") whereas what you have got in Python 2.7 is gibberish. Clearly, `dis` is decompiling the string as bytecode in 2.7 but compiling it as Python in 3.2.
3. I had a look in the source code for `dis.dis`. Here are the key points:

   Python 2.7:

   ```
   elif isinstance(x, str):
       disassemble_string(x)
   ```

   Python 3.2:

   ```
      elif isinstance(x, (bytes, bytearray)): # Raw bytecode
          _disassemble_bytes(x)
      elif isinstance(x, str):    # Source code
          _disassemble_str(x)
   ```

   Just for fun, let's check this by passing the same bytes to `dis` in Python 3:

   ```
   >>> dis.dis("i in (2,3)".encode())
             0 BUILD_MAP       26912
             3 JUMP_FORWARD    10272 (to 10278)
             6 <50>
             7 <44>
             8 <51>
             9 <41>
   ```

   Aha! Gibberish! (Though note that it's slightly different gibberish -- the bytecode has changed with the Python version!)

Comment: And here's the corresponding part of the doc
From the Python2 documentation ( http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html ):
>dis.dis([bytesource])

> Disassemble the bytesource object. 
> bytesource can denote either a module, a class, a method, a function, or a code object

whereas in the Python 3 documentation ( http://docs.python.org/dev/library/dis.html?highlight=dis#dis)  it states:
>dis.dis(x=None)

>Disassemble the x object. x can denote either a module, a class, a method, a function, a code object, **a string of source code** or a byte sequence of raw bytecode.

Answer (score 18):

`dis.dis` expects bytecode as an argument, not python source code. Although your first example "works", it doesn't provide any meaningful output. You probably want:

```
import compiler, dis

code = compiler.compile("i in [2, 3]", '', 'single')
dis.dis(code)
```

This works as expected. (I tested in 2.7 only).

Answer (score 9):

If you are just trying to get bytecode for a simple expression, passing it to dis as a lambda with your expression as the lambda's body is the simplest:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(lambda i : i in [3,2])
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 ((3, 2))
              6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```